# Cucumber Java how to update an element in a DataTable

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to follow an example in the Cucumber tutorial but it is written for Ruby and I am trying to write it in Java. I am having difficulty implementing the `@When` step as it requires me to update the DataTable and I am getting the following exception thrown,

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.set(Collections.java:1308)
at cucumber_tutorial.expressive_scenarios.chapter5.features.step_definitions.BoardSteps.player_x_plays_in_row_column(BoardSteps.java:36)
at ✽.When player x plays in row 2, column 1(tic_tac_toe.feature:8)
```

My Feature is as follows,

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
    Given a board like this:
      |   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
      | 1 |   |   |   |
      | 2 |   |   |   |
      | 3 |   |   |   |
    When player x plays in row 2, column 1
    Then the board should look like this:
      |   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
      | 1 |   |   |   |
      | 2 | x |   |   |
      | 3 |   |   |   |
```

After running the Feature and taking the generated Code snippets I have the following (I've added a couple of lines myself as well),

```
package cucumber_tutorial.expressive_scenarios.chapter5.features.step_definitions;

import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import java.util.List;

public class BoardSteps {

    List<List<String>> boardList;

    @Given("^a board like this:$")
    public void a_board_like_this(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
        boardList = dataTable.raw();
        System.out.println(boardList);
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
        // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
        //throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^player x plays in row (\\d+), column (\\d+)$")
    public void player_x_plays_in_row_column(int row, int col) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //board.
        //throw new PendingException()
        boardList.get(row).set(col, "x");
    }

    @Then("^the board should look like this:$")
    public void the_board_should_look_like_this(DataTable expectedTable) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
        // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
        expectedTable.diff(boardList);
        //throw new PendingException();
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be that `dataTable.raw()` in the `@Given` step assigns an Unmodifiable Collection type to `boardList` and so makes it un-updateable. 
The Ruby example simply has, ​

```
row, col = row.to_i, col.to_i​   
@board[row][col] = ​'x'​
```

my exception is thrown from,

```
boardList.get(row).set(col, "x"); //this line throws the exception
```

Can someone please advise me what the standard way is to update a DataTable using Java ?

Comment: Recreate a new datatable in ur code using the values in the existing datatable.

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks - could you please show an example of how to do that

Comment: Simplest would be to use a List<List<String> argument instead of DataTable in the stepdefinition. Then u can use looping to create a new List of List.

Comment: @Grasshopper thank you - your tip helped me to solve this problem - I will post my solution. I have to admit I am surprised that I have had to do it this way - it feels a bit inelegant.

Comment: U can look up the DataTable source code. Maybe there is a method which returns a modifiable structure, though I am doubtful. Guess the logic is that test data needs to be available at feature file level and not hidden in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Grasshopper suggested in the above comments, I have implemented a conversion function 
`convertDataTableToModifiableList` to convert the unmodifiable DataTable into a `List<List<String>>` object which I can update. My working solution is now as shown,

```
import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BoardSteps {

    List<List<String>> boardList;

    @Given("^a board like this:$")
    public void a_board_like_this(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
        boardList = convertDataTableToModifiableList(dataTable);
        System.out.println(boardList);
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
        // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
        //throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^player x plays in row (\\d+), column (\\d+)$")
    public void player_x_plays_in_row_column(int row, int col) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //board.
        //throw new PendingException()
        boardList.get(row).set(col, "x");
    }

    @Then("^the board should look like this:$")
    public void the_board_should_look_like_this(DataTable expectedTable) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
        // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
        expectedTable.diff(boardList);
        //throw new PendingException();
    }

    private List<List<String>> convertDataTableToModifiableList(DataTable dataTable){
        List<List<String>> lists = dataTable.asLists(String.class);
        List<List<String>> updateableLists = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++){
            List<String> list = lists.get(i);
            List<String> updateableList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
                updateableList.add(j, list.get(j));
            }
            updateableLists.add(i, updateableList);
        }
        return updateableLists;
    }

}
```

I am surprised there isn't a more elegant way of doing this, if you have a better suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with.

```
public class BoardSteps {

    private ArrayList<List<String>> board;

    @Given("a board like this:")
    public void aBoardLikeThis(DataTable board) {
        this.board = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (List<String> row: board.asLists()) {
            this.board.add(new ArrayList<String>(row));
        }

    }

    @When("player x plays in row {int}, column {int}")
    public void playerXPlaysInRowColumn(Integer row, Integer column) {
        this.board.get(row).set(column, "x");

    }

    @Then("the board should look like this:")
    public void theBoardShouldLookLikeThis(DataTable expectedBoard) {
        expectedBoard.diff(DataTable.create(board));
    }

}
```

Comment: not sure as I'm not familiar with this content, but should playerXPlaysInRawColumn actually be playerXPlaysInRowColumn? (Row vs Raw)

Comment: Well spotted @AlexHague. That was a typo.